# Android app crashes right after lanuch with simple java coding

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm going make this short and precise;

*I'm running ubuntu 14.04+

*running eclipse while connected to nexus 4 (ANDROID 4.3)

*started programing for android application where I only had the option to program at android level 5.1 (at the start of the program where it asks you to set).

So I launched the program at first and it gave this error

```
ERROR: Application requires API version 22. Device API version is 18 (Android 4.3)
```

I read online and changed things around in my

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="22"
android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

TO

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

BUT my app lanuches and crashes right away. Error produced in LOGCAT

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 495K, 6% free 9168K/9704K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
```

and thats where the program stops at in the console

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { 
    act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
    [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
    cmp=self.name.firstandroidprogram/.MainActivity
```

lastly here is my code in java

```
package self.name.firstandroidprogram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout1;
    TextView label1;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        label1 = new TextView(this);
        layout1.addView(layout1);

        setContentView(layout1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logs are not ok. Please provide the exception that makes your application to crash. GC_FOR_ALLOC is just a log to tell the system is reserving more memory and ActivityManager: Starting: Intent means you are starting an intent, but both are not errors itself

Comment: layout1.addView(layout1); - I think you meant to put your TextView instance as an argument here.

Comment: `minSdkVersion` specifies the oldest Android platform on which your app can run at all. `targetSdkVersion` specifies the newest platform which tools you want access to. For example if your user has Lollipop you'll want to use some APIs introduced in Android 5 to enhance their experience. Therefore you set `targetSdkVersion=22`. But your code may contain an ELSE block where you do without these new APIs which allows your app to run on Andoid 4, so you set `minSdkVersion=14`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your `MainActivity` to the `Android Manifest` ?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    .... >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have had such problems it has been due to missing libraries. Go to your SDK Manager and make sure you have the version of API and tools that you are compiling to. If not, BUST.